# radio inputs not working with angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, radio-button

I'm using radio inputs in a form, I put the same `ng-model` on both of them. But I can't get the  value in my controller, however I can get the value of the other `ng-model` fields.

You can find my code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBWLP/3/) and [codepen](http://codepen.io/Micka33/pen/Iuznx) (none of them are working for some reasons)

### Here is the haml form

```
%form.project{'ng-submit' => "createNewProject()"}
    .name
        %input{'ng-model'=>'name', :type => :text, :placeholder => 'Name', :name => "name"}
    .description
        %textarea{'ng-model'=>'description', :placeholder => 'Description', :required=>true, :name => "description"}
    .orientation
        %input#portrait{'ng-model'=>'orientation', :type=>"radio", :name=>"orientation", :value=>"1", :checked=>true}
        %label{:for=>"portrait"}
        %input#landscape{'ng-model'=>'orientation', :type=>"radio", :name=>"orientation", :value=>"2"}
        %label{:for=>"landscape"}
```

### Here is the controller

```
app.controller('theController', ['$scope', function($scope)
{

    $scope.createNewProject = function()
    {
        var item = {
                name:this.name,
                description:this.description,
                orientation:this.orientation
            };
        //item.orientation is undefined
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

In the controller, create the attribute orientation and set it to the default value you want your radios input to be set (remove the `:checked=>true` in the radio input).

### HAML

```
%input#portrait{'ng-model'=>'orientation', :type=>"radio", :name=>"orientation", :value=>"1"}
%label{:for=>"portrait"}
%input#landscape{'ng-model'=>'orientation', :type=>"radio", :name=>"orientation", :value=>"2"}
%label{:for=>"landscape"}
```

### CONTROLLER

```
app.controller('theController', ['$scope', function($scope)
{
    $scope.orientation = 1;
    $scope.createNewProject = function()
    {
        var item = {
                name:this.name,
                description:this.description,
                orientation:this.orientation
            };
        //item.orientation is undefined
    }

}]);
```

### The process is the following:

If you do not create the orientation attribute first, it won't be initialized until the radio inputs change, so you will have `this.orientation` undefined.

So the solution is to set the value of `$scope.orientation` in the controller.

It will create the attribute so you don't have it undefined, AND, set the radios input to a default position, so the `:checked=>true` becomes useless(and doesn't have any effect on the attribute anyway)